# Why does an instance of the keras Sequence iterate forever?

Tags: python, keras, generator

Here's a link to [the source code for the keras Sequence class][1].

I have created what I believe to be the exact same object by doing the following:

1. copying and pasting the same `__init__`, `__getitem__`, and `__len__` methods from the `InfiniteGenerator` class to the `KGen` class.
2. copying the **iter** method from the source code of the `Sequence` class the the `InfiniteGenerator` class.

My hypothesis is that these two generators should both create a finite list, but the `Sequence` object will continue iterating forever.  Why?

```
class InfiniteGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, alist):
        self.alist = alist

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.alist[idx]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.alist)

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in (self[i] for i in range(len(self))):
            yield item

from keras.utils import Sequence

class KGen(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, alist):
        self.alist = alist

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.alist[idx]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.alist)


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    ig = InfiniteGenerator(list(range(4)))
    for item in ig:
        print(item)


    print('now trying second iterator')

    import time
    time.sleep(1)

    kg = KGen(list(range(4)))
    for item in kg:
        print(item)
```

Comment: I run this code stopped once.

Comment: Weird.  There is no mistake in the code tough.  I just double checked by pasting this code into an ipython REPL, and I got the infinite loop on the second iterator.  I am using python3 that I installed with anaconda on my macbook.  I get the same result on Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue. The `idx` resets, but it just keeps running...

Comment: I've made an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11438

Comment: Hey.  No, I never figured it out.  It wasn't a problem for me, because fit_generator didn't seem to go into an infinite loop, but I posted here out of curiosity.

Comment: By any chance do you know what version of Keras you were using? I realized that before 2.2.3, they actually used an infinite generator. The change was made fairly recently, too, so I think it's quite possible that might have been the issue. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/5027630fa41f499a9226a8f9d952ceabf2c247aa#diff-ba9d38600a2df565e5ae8757eb2b1b35

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure, but I pip upgraded keras and tensorflow, and now when I run the script above, it does not loop infinitely as before.

Comment: Sounds like that was it, then :). Now just to figure out why the `next()` call in the `fit_generator` is also causing an endless loop in my project... 

Comment: When you find out, let me know.  I'm very curious.  I noticed that in the backend module, there are some `from <module> import *` statements.  I suspect Sequence may be getting imported from another library.

Comment: haha, I forgot to actually return something from my `__getitem__` method. Oh boy that took a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this as well using tensorflow.keras version 1.10.  You can see in the source code they defined `__iter__()` to return an infinite generator.  I added the following function to all of my Sequence classes to create a one-shot iterator for the situations where I need one.

```
def gen_iter(self):
    for i in range(len(self)):
        yield self[i]
```

Comment: can you link to that code?  It's okay if you won't.  I updated keras and now my program runs fine, but if it's easy for you, I'm curious.

Comment: [The Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py).  Lines 396-405.  I haven't looked to see if they modified it in current versions.